# How to parse Instant to RFC 2822 inside handlebars.java

Tags: kotlin, java-time, handlebars.java

I would like to pass `Instant` to `context` and display is as RFC 2822 String.

Currently, I parse it in the code:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(myInstant)
```

but I wonder is there any option to do it in the template?

Comment: I don’t know the answer to your question; but you may use the built-in [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) so you don’t need to write your own format pattern string. Usage: *parse* is the opposite of *format*.

Comment: @OleV.V. my question is about putting this logic into template instead of code. as a side-note this formatter will fail on instant - you need to customize it with `.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))` in order to make it working

Comment: Not knowing Handlebars but knowing java.time there’s no conflict in what you’re saying. `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")).format(Instant.now())` just gave `Thu, 23 Apr 2020 12:28:31 GMT` on my computer. There’s no reason why you can’t use `.withZone()` with a built-in formatter. You can, it’s straightforward to do.

Comment: @OleV.V. It's the opposite - when I do not use `withZone` then formatting crashes

Comment: Yes, obviously. There’s a time zone abbreviation in the format, so to produce it you need to supply a time zone. This can be done in the formatter as both you and I have demonstratoed, or it can be done in the formatted date and time — which would then need to be a `ZonedDateTime`.